# Programmatically configure Kafka Binder configurations through Beans instead of application.yml file

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm looking for a way to configure Kafka Binder configurations programmatically, especially brokers, topic info and a few Kafka consumer properties.

Why - I don't want to build and deploy the application every time there is a change in config (due to DR or otherwise)

I was looking into the [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) and couldn't find relevant sample to do so.

I tried creating Bean of `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.properties.KafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties` but then there are so many other properties to configure in that class and I don't know a way how to update `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsBinderSupportAutoConfiguration` to use the new instance instead.

I am looking to create similar [config as here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-two-kafka-clusters/src/main/resources/application.yml) programmatically. Is this even possible right now? Any help regarding this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. . . you don't need to build and deploy the application when changing properties. What made you think that?
You can provide application configuration properties as standard command line options via `-D` flag (e.g., `-Dspring.cloud.function.definition=blah`).

Comment: thanks, Oleg, I'm aware of this, as well as I can pass property file using `-Dspring.config.location=x`. What I need instead is Java based specifically as we've our own configuration management server and during boot up we fetch the values and instantiate components accordingly (viz. db, thread pool config etc.) So lets say if we need to update any property we update at the config server and restart the app.

Comment: ` if we need to update any property we update at the config server and restart the app` - You can do it today - https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config

Comment: we already have a config server, and thats not Spring based :( cant bring up a new config server just for this app

Comment: Then you can simply do `System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "x");` somewhere in your custom code